# Add a function or parameter to OData controller

Tags: asp.net-core, controller, overriding, odata, aspnetboilerplate

I'm using ASP.NET Boilerplate framework for ASP.NET Core. I have the boilerplate OData controllers as per https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/OData-AspNetCore-Integration.

I want to support passing of a custom parameter in either the GET method or in a custom OData function. How do I do this in the `AbpODataEntityController`?

Regards,
David

Comment: You can try overriding these virtual methods https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/dev/src/Abp.AspNetCore.OData/AspNetCore/OData/Controllers/AbpODataEntityController.cs#L33-L45

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add custom function to AbpODataEntityController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55164203/how-to-add-custom-function-to-abpodataentitycontroller)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source code, it looks like they are using the standard "Microsoft.AspNet.OData" Version="7.1.0".

So you probably have a place where you set up your `EdmModel`.
You should create a function in your controller like this:

```cs
// odata/Tenants/Default.IsDomainAvailable('<domain name here>')
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult IsDomainAvailable([FromODataUri] string domainName)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest();
    try
    {
        var item = _unitOfWork.Tenants
            .FindByHostName(domainName)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        if (item == null) 
            return Ok(string.Format("{0} is available", domainName));

        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status409Conflict, string.Format("{0} is not available", domainName));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Then you can just declare a function in your EDM model builder like this:

```cs
private void BuildFunctions(ODataModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.EntityType<TenantDTO>().Collection
        .Function("IsDomainAvailable")
        .Returns<IActionResult>()
        .Parameter<string>("domainName");
}
```

And call it from Postman like this:

```cs
odata/Tenants/Default.IsDomainAvailable('<domain name here>')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's `Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData`.