# How to add custom function to AbpODataEntityController?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata, aspnetboilerplate

In a recent [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51625228/add-a-function-or-parameter-to-odata-controller/54161835), there is some suggestion about how to add a custom function to an `AbpODataEntityController`. I have tried but I can't achieve what I want.

For example, in my `AbpODataEntityController`, there are two methods called `Test` and `EchoTest`.

```
public class TownsController : AbpODataEntityController<Town>, ITransientDependency
{
    public TownsController(IRepository<Town> repository) : base(repository)
    {
    }

    // [HttpPost]
    public string Test()
    {
        return "inanc";
    }

    // [HttpPost]
    // [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult EchoTest([FromODataUri] string param)
    {
        return Ok(string.Format("The param was {0}", param));
    }
}
```

And my Startup.cs has:

```
builder.EntityType<Town>().Collection
    .Function("Test")
    .Returns<string>();
    //.Parameter<string>("param");

builder.EntityType<Town>()//.Action("stringTest")
    .Function("EchoTest")
    .Returns<IActionResult>()
    .Parameter<string>("param");
```

The simple function `Test` is OK. It gives a result as:

> {"@odata.context":"http://localhost:21021/odata/$metadata#Edm.String","value":"inanc"}

But the function with a parameter with name `param` doesn't work. I get 404 error.

I call the method by http://localhost:21021/odata/towns/EchoTest?param=foo.

Where did I go wrong? I should have some custom function that accepts parameters.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `.Collection`:

```cs
builder.EntityType<Town>().Collection
    .Function("EchoTest")
    .Returns<IActionResult>()
    .Parameter<string>("param");
```

The correct URL: http://localhost:21021/odata/Towns/Default.EchoTest(param='foo')

Comment: You are a very good teacher aaron. You are my idol! Thank you very much..